# How to rollback 3 statements if one fails?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

In C#, I have three statements in a method that insert data into a database.  The first statement inserts and I get an ID from it.  This ID is used in the next two statements.

I have two cases to handle:

1.) The second statement can return false if certain input conditions aren't met.  In that case, I'd like to rollback the first statement.
2.) If either of the statements generate an error, they should all rollback.

I thought to wrap all three statements in a transaction scope but it will only rollback on exceptions, which only covers the second case.  What is the best way handle both cases?

I'm using DataContext via a DBML with LINQ 2 SQL

Comment: I don't know about c# SQL, but in mysql there is a way to roll back transaction without exception

Comment: Why do you think it only rolls back in exceptions? You have to explicitly commit. You know under what circumstances you do not want to commit. dot dot dot

Comment: Each of the three statements are also methods that do commit.

Comment: @4thSpace `BEGIN TRAN` moves out one level and `COMMIT` moves back one level. `ROLLBACK` moves back *all* levels. So if you nest your three transactions within 1 super-transaction, nothing is *really committed* until super-tran is committed but everything is rolled back if anything rolls back.

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to working directly in the database.  I'm referring to .NET code only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With TransactionScope() you need to call Complete() method to commit the changes.
Othewise all pending changes will be rolled back, so your (1) is also covered

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link I posted. Its pretty simple to manually roll back a transaction

[How to Commit and Rollback Transaction in .NET](http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/06/how-to-commit-and-rollback-transaction.html)

The jist of it is that after you have your transaction object, you can call [`RollBack()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.rollback%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on it.

For Linq-To-Sql take a look at [How to: Bracket Data Submissions by Using Transactions (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387002.aspx)

Comment: That looks great but I'm not using ADO.NET.  I'm using DataContext via a DBML with LINQ 2 SQL.

Comment: added link for linq2sql at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Bad link 404 on How to Commit and Rollback Transaction in .NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) statement, with the right severity level (18 I believe should do it) to "throw an exception" and cause your transaction to rollback under user-checked conditions.

Obviously though, this will only rollback anything within the same transaction scope.